# Коллекция LIst привязалась к другой коллекции c# wpf

Tags: c#, list

в мой код вселился демон, моя функция присылает пустую коллекцию, при отладке заметил такую вещь, что в коллекции `data` сохраняются все вложенные коллекции, но правда данные в них напрямую привязаны к коллекции `temp`. При выполнении данной строчки кода `temp.Clear();` данные во вложенных коллекциях обнуляются и по тому же принципу заполняются. В голову даже не приходит, что же могло послужить такому поведению кода.

```
public List<List<String>> LoadMenu()
{
    String sql = "SELECT Chapters.Id, Chapters.Title, Chapters.Number," +
            " Topics.Id, Topics.Id_chapter, Topics.Name, Topics.Position FROM" +
            " Chapters LEFT JOIN Topics ON" +
            " Chapters.Id = Topics.Id_chapter" +
            " ORDER BY Chapters.Number ASC; ";

    // Полученные данные разделенные на строки
    List<List<String>> data = new List<List<string>>();

    // Временные данные для сохранение одной строки
    List<String> temp = new List<string>();

    Connect();
    using (SQLiteCommand qLiteCommand = new SQLiteCommand(sql, _connectLocalDB))
    {
        using(SQLiteDataReader qLiteDataReader = qLiteCommand.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (qLiteDataReader.HasRows)
            {
                while (qLiteDataReader.Read())
                {
                    for (Int32 column = 0; column < qLiteDataReader.FieldCount; column++)
                    {
                        temp.Add(qLiteDataReader[column].ToString());
                    }
                    data.Add(temp);
                    temp.Clear();
                }
                MessageBox.Show(qLiteDataReader.StepCount.ToString());
            }
            Disconnect();
            return data;
        }
    }
}

public Boolean Connect()
{
    /*try
    {*/
    _connectLocalDB = new SQLiteConnection(_connect);
    _connectLocalDB.Open();
    return true;
    /*}
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }*/
}

public Boolean Disconnect()
{
    try
    {
        _connectLocalDB.Close();
        _connectLocalDB = null;
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `data.Add(temp);` Вы все время добавляете один и тот же список `temp`.

```
using (SQLiteCommand qLiteCommand = new SQLiteCommand(sql, _connectLocalDB))
{
    using(SQLiteDataReader qLiteDataReader = qLiteCommand.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (qLiteDataReader.HasRows)
        {
            while (qLiteDataReader.Read())
            {
                List<String> temp = new List<string>();
                for (Int32 column = 0; column < qLiteDataReader.FieldCount; column++)
                {
                    temp.Add(qLiteDataReader[column].ToString());
                }
                data.Add(temp);
            }
```